# Is the following PDE solvable?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am considering the PDE of the following type
$$\frac{\partial W}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial^{2} W}{\partial x^{2}},$$ $ u>0,\:0<x<\infty$ such that $W(0,x)=\delta(x)$. I wonder if this problem is solvable and the corresponding solution if it is solvable.

Another PDE that I would like to consider is as follow:
$$\frac{\partial W}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial^{2} W}{\partial x^{2}},$$ $ u>0,\:\theta(u)<x<\infty$ such that $W(0,x)=\delta(x)$, $\theta(0)=0<x<\infty$ and $W(u,\theta(u))=0$. This is a PDE of moving boundary. Is it possible to decompose $W=W^{1}+W^{2}$ such that
$$\frac{\partial W^{1}}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial^{2} W^{1}}{\partial x^{2}},$$ $ u>0,\:-\infty<x<\infty$ such that $W^{1}(0,x)=\delta(x)$ and
$$\frac{\partial W^{2}}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial^{2} W^{2}}{\partial x^{2}},$$ $ u>0,\:\theta(u)<x<\infty$ such that $W^{2}(u,\theta(u))=-W^{1}(u,\theta(u))$, $W^{2}(0,x)=0$?

Comment: Did you considered $W(u,x) = U(u)X(x)$ ?

Comment: Using separating of variable? Of course I tried before.

Comment: hello have you considered a solving it Fourier Series. check wikipedia there is a soluton detailed there. i think Fourier is your best bet

Comment: Fourier Method should not work on a moving boundary problem.

Comment: The first problem is solvable via Fourier transform. The solution is $W = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}$

Comment: I think of it, since it is just the same solution as thinking of infinite domain, I wonder if it is correct.

Comment: Maybe I'm just being dumb, but how are you defining $\delta(x)$ on your domain?  As an element of the dual space of $C^\infty_c((0, \infty))$, $\delta(x) = 0$.

Comment: Can we have a physical meaning that placing a heat source at the point 0 giving an initial pulse at time 0, and then let the heat transfer throughout time in the space $0<x<\infty$